How do I safely handle memory allocation errors in C?
I’m working on a C program that requires dynamic memory allocation for an array of structures. I understand that using malloc can sometimes fail, returning NULL. However, I’m unsure of the best practices for handling these situations to prevent undefined behavior or memory leaks.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[50];
} Item;

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of items: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    Item *items = (Item *)malloc(n * sizeof(Item));

    if (items == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    free(items);
    return 0;
}

My questions are:

Is my current error handling sufficient for detecting memory allocation failures?
What additional steps can I take to ensure robust memory management in larger applications?
Are there any specific debugging techniques for tracking memory leaks or allocation issues in C?

Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Let's see if we have some relevant answers already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7940279/21105992 https://stackoverflow.com/q/70448444/21105992 https://stackoverflow.com/q/413477/21105992

What OS are you using?   FYR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind

This code looks fine: an error message on stderr and a different code returned to the environment. One single not so good point, you cast the return of malloc, which you should never do in C language

a) you aren't checking whether scanf() succeeded, (b) even if it does, you are allowing negative values, and not checking the range of n (c) please see Do I cast the result of malloc?, (d) better as sizeof *items than as sizeof(Item).

This almost feels like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

This is how I would change it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[50];
} Item;

int main() {
    // NOTE: Don't allow negative values if you don't want them
    // int n = 0;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of items: ");

    // NOTE: scanf() returns the number of elemets red or negative on failure.

    //scanf("%d", &n);          
    if(scanf("%u", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a number!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    
    // NOTE: No cast from or to 'void *' needed in C.
    // NOTE: Multiplication is especially dangerous here,
    //       because of overflow. calloc() does that for you.
    //       You could end up with less memory than expected.
    //       A hacker could get access to all your memory.
    // NOTE: Use sizeof(*items), it is easier to maintain.

    // Item *items = (Item *)malloc(n * sizeof(Item));
    Item *items = calloc(n, sizeof(*items));

    if (!items) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // NOTE: You could set the pointer to NULL afterwards.
    //       PRO: Bugs are less dangerous,
    //            the program might crash more orderly.
    //       CON: Bugs are harder to find,
    //            valgrind detects access-after-free,
    //            and provides useful information.
    //            All this does not work if set to NULL.
    free(items);
#ifdef RELEASE
    items = NULL;
#endif
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}


Yes, n * sizeof(Item) may overflow the multiplication and not get detected.  calloc() is one approach.

As an addition to @Lundin answer:

Item *items = (Item *)malloc(n * sizeof(Item)); - do not cast the result of malloc. If your code does not compile without it it means that you are compiling the C language program using C++ compiler - which is wrong as C and C++ are different languages.

if (items == NULL) { When programming under many modern OS-es this check will not check if you have allocated the memory. It is called an "optimistic allocation strategy" and memory can be overcommitted. The program may fail at any time due to insufficient available memory. The memory will not be allocated before the first use. his check on modern OS-es will only check if you have not destroyed the internal malloc structures by writing outside the array bounds.



"which is wrong as C and C++ are different languages" Unless the intention is to write compatible code for portability reasons, making the code compile in both C and C++.

@Lundin no - it is wrong. C++ and C have different rules and C code must be compiled by C compiler. C++/C portability - lovely.

"C++/C portability" Writing protocol stacks, libraries, RTOS and the like for multiple targets often requires just that. Maximum portability is a key selling point.

@Lundin the correct way when you use C functions in C++ is: 1. Compile C code using C compiler. 2. Wrap declarations in extern "C" and use in C++ code 3. Link together.  If one does it another way - it does not sound very professional



Is my current error handling sufficient for detecting memory allocation failures?


The main problem in your code isn't really related to malloc but that you take non-sanitized input and feed it directly to the program. You should check if scanf failed or not. Or better yet, avoid stdio.h entirely whenever possible.
In a professional program you need to sanity check that n is within given boundaries. It also makes no sense at all to use a signed integer to express array size because it can never be negative.



What additional steps can I take to ensure robust memory management in larger applications?


It's good practice overall to:

Initialize all pointers that are to be used for dynamic memory to NULL.
Set every pointer to NULL immediately after calling free.

Also for small amounts of memory there's usually no need to allocate memory dynamically in the first place. Data which is just some hundred bytes could safely be allocated on the stack in most cases.



Are there any specific debugging techniques for tracking memory leaks or allocation issues in C?


There are tools for static analysis or dynamic analysis.
Static analyzers check your code at compile time (beyond what the compiler already may or may not check) for things like array out of bounds access, dangling pointer bug etc. Dynamic analyzers check the program for bugs as it is running and is able to spot memory leaks that way.
Examples: gcc has some options both for static and dynamic analysis these days, check out Instrumentation Options. For example -fsanitize=address which can spot a lot of memory-related problems. For other free open source options, there's tools like Clang-Tidy, Valgrid, Frama-C and so on.

Some problems with:
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    Item *items = (Item *)malloc(n * sizeof(Item));
    if (items == NULL) {


scanf("%d", &n) may fail due to non-numeric input.  Code lacks a return value check.   Add check.

n < 0 is possible resulting is n converted to a large size_t value that certainly overflows n * sizeof(Item) with a product that might pass allocation, yet is just wrong here.  Use size_t n and matching scan specifier.

n * sizeof(Item) ricks overflow when n is large.  A n/sizeof(Item) <= SIZE_MAX would insure product is in range.

When n == 0, allocation returning NULL may be acceptable.  I'd use if (items == NULL && n > 0)  to test for error.


